# Laravel can't instantiate interface via __construct (using App::bind)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to resolve class via `__construct` using Laravel's `bind()` method.

Here what I do:

`routes.php` (of course I will move it away from here)

```
// Bindings
App::bind(
    'License\Services\ModuleSelector\SelectorInterface',
    'License\Services\ModuleSelector\ModuleSelector'
);
```

`SelectorInterface.php` - interface that I will expect in `__construct` method.

```
<?php namespace License\Services\ModuleSelector;


interface SelectorInterface {

    /**
     * Simply return query that will select needle module fields
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function make();

}
```

`ModuleSelector.php` - this is class that I want to resolve via Laravel's DI (see example below).

```
<?php namespace License\Services\ModuleSelector;    

use License\Services\ModuleSelector\Selector;   

class ModuleSelector extends Selector
{       
    /**
     * Get module by it's code
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function find()
    {
        return $this->make()
            ->where('code', $module_code)
            ->first();
    }    
}
```

`Module.php`

```
<?php namespace License\Services\ModuleType;    

use License\Services\ModuleType\TypeInterface;
use License\Services\ModuleSelector\SelectorInterface;    

class Module 
{    
    ...    

    function __construct(SelectorInterface $selector)
    {
        $this->selector = $selector;
    }
    ...
}
```

And the place when error occurs:

In my repo I have `use License\Services\ModuleType\Module as ModuleService;`.

Than there is method called `find()`:

```
/**
 * Find module by its code with all data (types, selected type)
 * @return mixed
 */
public function find($module_code)
{
    $module = new ModuleService;

    // Get module id in order to use build in relations in framework
    $module = $this->module->find($module_code);

    ...
}
```

So, in other words, I have 2 classes and one interface. What I am trying to do is:

1) Create `Class1.php` / `Class2.php` / `Class2Interface.php`.

2) In `Class1.php` in the `__construct` I specify `__construct(Class2Interface $class2)`.

3) Instantiate `Class2`.

What I am doing wrong? Examples found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc).

Comment: Of course not. I am trying to instansiate class by passing interface to the __construct using some kind of ReflectionClass. It is the basic functional from Laravel DI

Comment: What's the actual error you get?

Comment: Argument 1 passed to License\Services\ModuleType\Module::__construct() must be an instance of License\Services\ModuleSelector\SelectorInterface, none given

Comment: I don't see where are you trying to pass the instance?

Comment: I am not passing it at all. It is all about ReflectionClass and ioc container. As was said in documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#where-to-register) I am binding it here App::bind(...);

Comment: "Since we have bound the UserRepositoryInterface to a concrete type, the DbUserRepository will automatically be injected into this controller when it is created"

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
$module = new ModuleService;
```

You are directly invoking the Module class and not passing in an instance of `SelectorInterface`.

For the IoC to work you bind **and** make classes using it. Try that line again with :

```
$module = App::make('License\Services\ModuleSelector\SelectorInterface');
```

An alernative is to inject it directly into your repos constructor, as long as the repo is created by the IoC container, your concrete will be automatically injected.

Comment: Nope, it is not working. I think, you misunderstood me a little bit. The goal is to resolve ModuleSelector class via SelectorInterface (because ModuleSelector implements SelectorInterface). But Module class is just a simple php class that expects SelectorInterface in __construct(SelectorInterface $selector).

Comment: Yes, that is why you use the IoC to build the class and not invoke it manually with 'new'. I just re-read your comment to see if I misunderstood, but i don't think I have. To have automatic dependency resolution of any class that's dependencies are available, make it with the IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere do you have a class marked to actually "implement SelectorInterface".